how to create a remote repository with borgwarehouse
Can someone help me with BorgWarehouse?
I don’t know how to create a remote repository on BorgWarehouse. I can do this using the CLI, but nothing appears in BorgWarehouse—the storage remains at 0.0%.
Here is a screenshot of the repository on BorgWarehouse:
repository on borgwarehouse
I also tried modifying the .env/.local file, but nothing changed:.env/.local modification
